# mobile version is shown on PC, instead of desktop version in chrome browser

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am making a website using bootstrap, and all by sudden, the mobile version is shown in google chrome instead of the desktop (using a laptop, not a phone). It does not matter if Inspect element is open or not. In both case the mobile version is shown.

I checked my website on internet explorer, it works fine.

In google chrome, if I choose the toggle device toolbar it is also working fine.

Things I tried: 
My google chrome is updated.
I reset the laptop and visual studio.
I cleared cookies.
Does anybody know what is the problem? 
By the way, I am using visual studio code(text editor).

This a screenshot of the website on localhost, i did not zoomed. as you see the navbar toggle is shown for desktop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClpBc.jpg

Update: the problem is fixed with reinstalling google chrome!

Comment: console view opened?

Comment: no it is not opened.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the `Developer tools` by pressing `F12` on the keyboard.
2. Click on the mobile toggle button which is in the left of the `element` tab. Or you can use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + M`.
   [image: Click here to see the icon]
3. Your mobile view mode will be closed.

Comment: but i am having the mobile version even when developer toolbar is closed. it is not related to inspect element.

Comment: Can you send me something so that I can understand it and help you?

Comment: I am not allowed to post a photo :(

Comment: But you are allowed to post a link of the photo.

Comment: Can you share your code!

Comment: You can use https://send.firefox.com/ to send code.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vM3aax6 here is a screenshot of my website. as you see the toggle device mode is not on.

Comment: Have you zoomed the screen?

Comment: If not, there might be some other vulnerability there, I can only help you if send me the code. I will not publish anywhere. If you want to then you can mail me, send your email.

Comment: no. not zooming. it is exactly like the version for mobile. you see the navbar is toggled.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can't help!